# What is the best method to implement Authentication/Authorization for VueJs frontend and Azure functions app backend

Tags: azure, vue.js, authentication, authorization, azure-functions

I am building a system that consists of frontend SPA build using VueJs and backend consists of a set of Azure functions (C#). I am done with the prototype and I am adding users authentication/authorization feature to the application. The application is B2B, so no need for external identity providers and there is no signup as well. All the users will be created by the system admins.
I have multiple options to choose from:

1. Develop the authentication/authorization/users management myself.
2. Use Azure AD B2C
3. Use Auth0 services

I did not use #2 and #3 before. I need help to choose the better option for my needs. or maybe there are better options.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding (2), it seems you don't need to use Azure AD B2C, given that you will not authenticate with external identities. A better alternative is to create a [multi-tenant SaaS application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps) and offer it to other Azure AD tenants of your choice (even the free tier might cover your needs). For your Vue.js client, you can leverage [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) and you can use [Microsoft.Identity.Web](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web) to protect your Azure Function app

Have a look at these [code samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#multi-tenant-saas-applications).